# calculate difference in time in days, hours and minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, time

UPDATE: I am updating the question to reflect the full solution. Using the time_diff gem Brett mentioned below, the following code worked.

code:

```
cur_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Time.diff(Time.parse('2011-08-12 09:00'), Time.parse(cur_time))
```

Thanks, Brett.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [time_diff](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff) to achieve this sort of thing easily before, you may want to check it out.

Comment: I am getting "undefined method `gsub!' for 2011-08-04 11:14:24 -0400:Time". I am trying to determine which file to place "require 'time_diff'" and "time_diff_components = Time.diff(start_date_time, end_date_time)". This is compatible with rails 3 too i assume.

Comment: i place the require in application.rb before module and the "time_diff..." in the module... right? ...hmm... that's not working.

Comment: I'm running rails3.1.rc4 - putting `gem 'time_diff'` in my Gemfile was good enough, I didn't have to explicitly require it.  Version 0.2.1 is doing just fine for me.

Comment: If you are getting errors, though, can you add the code that is causing them below your question (with an edit)?

Comment: see update above. Got it working if i insert the dates, so the gem does work all by itself. When i use a helper to get the time it produces an error. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Without using a external gem, you can easily get differences between dates using a method like this:

```
def release(time)
  delta = time - Time.now

  %w[days hours minutes].collect do |step|
    seconds = 1.send(step)
    (delta / seconds).to_i.tap do
      delta %= seconds
    end
  end
end

release(("2011-08-12 09:00:00").to_time)
# => [7, 17, 37]
```

which will return an array of days, hours and minutes and can be easily extended to include years, month and seconds as well:

```
def release(time)
  delta = time - Time.now

  %w[years months days hours minutes seconds].collect do |step|
    seconds = 1.send(step)
    (delta / seconds).to_i.tap do
      delta %= seconds
    end
  end
end

release(("2011-08-12 09:00:00").to_time)
# => [0, 0, 7, 17, 38, 13]
```

Comment: Hey, @ream88. Your solution worked as well. I like the gem tho. +1 for your help.