# Time difference in words using Ruby ActiveRecord Timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, timestamp

I'm building an application using Postgres and Ruby Gem `ActiveRecord`.

When a user data is being stored in the database, I'm keeping track of the time it was created by using the `timestamps` method that gives me a `created_at` field.

I'm looking for a way of calculating the time difference from created_at timestamp till now and present it as a text like so:

***"23 minutes ago"** or **"16 hours ago"** or **"2 months ago"** or **"last year"**.*

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out the solution postet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943692/calculate-difference-in-time-in-days-hours-and-minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to checkout these helper methods - [time_ago_in_words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) and [distance_of_time_in_words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words)

Edit- Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/195883/326543), it has more details.